# Apify - save JSON output to key-store-value

Tags: javascript, json, apify

how can I save JSON output of this script to key-store-value in Apify?
when I run script everything is working fine dataset show me every types of scraped data but key-value-store/Keys is still empty. Are any simple commands for do that for me?
here is my Actor code:

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
    
    const metamorphInput = {
        "runMode": "DEVELOPMENT",
        "startUrls": [
            {
                "url": "https://mapa.covid.chat/table",
                "method": "GET"
            }
        ],
        "useRequestQueue": false,
        "keepUrlFragments": false,
        "pageFunction": // The function accepts a single argument: the "context" object.
        
        function pageFunction(context) {
        
            var $ = context.jQuery;
            const now = new Date();
            var towns = [];
            $("tr").each(function(data){
                towns.push({
                    city: ($(this).find("a").text()),
                    infected: ($(this).find(".text-right.infected").text().trim()),
                    todayNew: ($(this).find("sup").text().trim()),
                    lastFindCase: ($(this).find(".small-info").text()),
    
                });
            });
        
            return {towns}
        },
        "injectJQuery": true,
        "injectUnderscore": false,
        "proxyConfiguration": {
            "useApifyProxy": false
        },
        "proxyRotation": "RECOMMENDED",
        "useChrome": false,
        "useStealth": false,
        "ignoreSslErrors": false,
        "ignoreCorsAndCsp": false,
        "downloadMedia": true,
        "downloadCss": true,
        "waitUntil": [
            "networkidle2"
        ],
        "breakpointLocation": "NONE",
        "debugLog": false,
        "browserLog": false
    };
    
    // Now let's metamorph into actor apify/web-scraper using the created input.
    await Apify.metamorph('apify/web-scraper', metamorphInput);
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of Web Scraper is a dataset. But you can store into Key-Value store from `pageFunction` with `await context.setValue('OUTPUT', towns)`. Not sure why you want to metamorph as well.
https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper#setvaluekey-data-options-asyncfunction

Comment: Is there anyway how can i use const kvStore = await Apify.openKeyValueStore('my-data); in function pageFunction(context){}   ??

Comment: You cannot do it with setValue. There is a workaround though and that is to use the fetch (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) function and call Apify API directly. https://docs.apify.com/api/v2#/reference/key-value-stores/record/put-record